Azure Blob Storage - private container access
In Azure Blob storage, I have one container with private access set on it.
I want to share access to the file in that container. I know that that is possible to achive by using SAS tokens. But I wonder if it is possible to give access to that file wihtout SAS token, for example:
When user access the link https://company.blob.core.windows.net/container/folder/file.png
The user is promted to login to azure account in order to access that specific file. Is this possible to do?
Thank you in advance, for the answers :)

You mean, you give out the link like above to your user. They paste it in the browser and somehow automatically redirected to Azure AD for auth and then redirected back? Or do you want your users to access it programmatically?

@GauravMantri yes - They paste it in the browser and somehow automatically redirected to Azure AD for auth and then redirected back

Unfortunately this won't work.

This feature may require a separate web app.


The user is promted to login to azure account in order to access that specific file. Is this possible to do?

According to this MS-Document,
I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment, it is not possible to access the files without authenticating with SAS token or programmatically with Azure AD authentication (access token).
The storage account creates the container with private by default, if the storage account is private, you need access through either by account key, SAS token or Microsoft Azure AD authentication.
If you need to access the blob link without SAS token or Microsoft Azure AD authentication, you can change the container access level to public (Container and blob) but this method is not approachable, and it is risky.
Portal:

